# Facebook Authentication Showing facebook Button instead of Permission Box

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api

1. I use below method to Authenticate..

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=&redirect_uri=&scope=email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,read_stream,user_about_me,offline_access,user_likes&response_type=code&display=page

2 Problem is that instead of Showing Permission Page facebook showing its own Button then when i cick on that button it showing Pemission Page...

FYI When i hit this link directly to browser it is working fine. But through my website it is as above.

How to avoid this button to appear and directly show permission page to user..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Bug from facebook..

Now it is working fine..